# My "Acer Aspire ES 15" laptop with Windows 10 pre-installed, does not let me turn off secure boot

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, linux-mint, acer-aspire, secure-boot

I have installed Linux Mint 18 on my Acer Aspire ES 15 laptop which has Windows 10 pre-installed on it. But, I am not able to boot into the Linux OS as the machine is always booting into Windows 10 automatically.
I went into the UEFI firmware settings, but not able to select the "secure boot" option to turn it off.

How can I dual boot into Linux and Windows as required? Please advise.

Thanks
Srini

Comment: You told you went into UEFI firmware settings? Its was in BIOS?. Did you try access UEFI firmware settings in Windows 10. Where you can go Window 10 Settings -- Update & security -- Recovery --- In Advanced Startup Click on Restart. Where it will boot to Advanced Startup. Go to Troubleshoot --- Advanced options -- See you can see UEFI Firmware Settings. If yes select that and Restart. where its restart your system and boot you straight in UEFI settings.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I did to get into UEFI firmware settings. But, like I mentioned, I was not able to select the "secure boot" option to turn it off. Do you mean, I don't need to turn off the "secure boot" in order to dual boot with Linux mint?

Comment: I've seen claims that Acers put extra hurdles in place; you must select an option in the firmware setup utility to trust the boot loader you're using. See [this question on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot) for more information; and in particular, look at steps 34-41 in the first answer. Note that I don't own an Acer, so I can't help beyond pointing to these instructions.

Answer (score 0):

If above comment didn't work. Then there may be issue in GRUB you need fix it.

- Go to Windows 10 PC. CMD run as administrator.
- Run below command

> bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi

It may prompt for Password. If this command runs good. Restart your system Check whether you are getting GRUB Screen.

Comment: I did this and got "The operation completed successfully". After this, I have restarted the machine and it booted to Windows 10 again.

Comment: Then you need reinstall it step by step process. Refer this link and follow the steps
[Link](https://www.tecmint.com/install-linux-mint-18-alongside-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot-uefi-mode/)